# Telescope find_files finds garbage instead of wanted file

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

I am new to NeoVim and Telescope so I tried to use [NvChad](https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad)

When I try to use :Telescope find_files and write whole name of file that exist only in one place in entire project - telescope instead of finding that one particular file shows me thousands of files in where max 3 characters match.

Do you have any ideas why that is?
Or maybe I am using it somehow wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening nvim in a particular directory ie `nvim path/to/my/project`? If not, it's likely that's your issue as it's searching your entire computer for a match as you didn't specify that working directory.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the find files ( `<leader>ff` ) use the find all ( `<leader>fa` ). It works as expected